# How to convert responsive PNG img HTML to SVG img in react

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to convert a responsive img tag that uses different image sizes.

```
<img src="/img/theme/home/product-infra_x2.png" class="features__column__figure__img" srcset="/img/theme/home/product-infra_x3.png 1200w, /img/theme/home/product-infra_x2.png 800w" height="640" width="800" sizes="(max-width: 32em) 160px, 1200px" loading="lazy" alt="Image 1">
```

Now I will like to change this to use an SVG image file and keep the responsiveness and image sizing as same in react.

Here is what I have

```
import image1 from './images/image1.svg'
import image2 from './images/image2.svg'


<img src={image1} className="features__column__figure__img" height="640" width="800" sizes="(max-width: 32em) 160px, 1200px" loading="lazy" alt="Image 1">
...
...
...
<img src={image2} className="features__column__figure__img" height="640" width="800" sizes="(max-width: 32em) 160px, 1200px" loading="lazy" alt="Image 2">
```

But the images are not sized well and they are having different widths and heights for different SVG images.

how can I have the SVG responsive like it was setup with the HTML version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use css option `object-fit: contain;` in your `className="features__column__figure__img"`.

[about object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Check_green_icon.svg"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: i want to keep the image itself but fit with width or height whichever limit comes first...so image can be resized width or height to fit the container...mind explaining if your answer helps do this?

Comment: So, image inside conteiner with object-fit should be resized to fit its container. Red border is conteiner itself. And when you will to resize conteiner, image will resize  also.

Comment: much better answer..thanks!...will test in a few before marking as answer...again thanks for a much better answer

Comment: problem with this answer is that ..when it scales height and there is space underneath, then elements below are higher compared to others...imagine using this on a 3 column container? how can i restrict the width and height so things below the images are aligned no matter what?

Comment: I guess the issue is in reset style. I did update snippet.